# Discord.js V13 Welcome Message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm still fairly new to creating bots, so this welcome message worked back in discord.js v12 but no longer works for me in v13. I am trying to send a message in a specific channel when someone joins the server, but I checked, and `.send` does not exist on GuildChannel. I checked to documentation but they all talk about sending message embeds, but I'm just trying to send a plain message to `TextChannel` Here is the code.

```js
const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });
```

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', guildMember => {
    guildMember.guild.channels.cache.get('474431129613762571').send(`**Welcome to the discord server, <@${guildMember.user.id}>!**`);
});
```

I can provide more information if needed. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You need `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent in both the code and discord developer portal. The `.send` exists on `TextChannel`s, `GuildChannel` is just what it extends and `.send` isn't there because it could be a `VoiceChannel`! (actually `TextChannel` extends `BaseGuildTextChannel` which extends `GuildChannel`)

Comment: @MrMythical Do you want to leave your advice as a comment? cause it worked for me and I want to give you credit for it but it's not an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `GUILD_MEMBERS` intent in both the code and discord developer portal.

```js
const client = new Client({ 
    intents: [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS //also enable in discord developer portal
    ] 
})
```

To answer the other part of your other question, the `.send` exists on `TextChannel`s. `TextChannel` extends `BaseGuildTextChannel` which extends `GuildChannel`. It's like this because it can be a `VoiceChannel`!